# Calling a function in class A from a thread in class B [C#]

Tags: c#

Now with all the WaitOne and ManualResetEvent stuff working (thanks!) I've got one last problem, that is running a function in Class A from a thread which is part of Class B - again allow me to illustrate ...

Look at the function "DoIt(obejct param)" within class A, this needs to be called by class A (as shown) as well as by the thread in class B (as shown) ... how can this be accomplished? Would some form of delegates help?

```
class A
{
private ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent;
int counter = 0;

public A()
    {
    manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    B child = new B(manualResetEvent);

    if (manualResetEvent.WaitOne(1000, false))
        {
        ... do the work I was waiting on ...
        }

    ... do more work ...
    // Call the function DoIt from within A //
    DoIt(param)

    }

    // This is the function that needs to be called from A and thread in B
    void DoIt(object param)
    {
    counter++;
    ... do something with param with is local to A ...
    }

};


Class B
{
private ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent;

public B(ManualResetEvent mre)
    {
    manualResetEvent = mre;
    Thread childThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Manage));
    childThread.IsBackground = true;
    childThread.Name = "NamedPipe Manager";
    childThread.Start();

    private void Manage()
        {
        ... do some work ...
        ... call some functions ...

        // Calling the function from Class A, obviouslly doesn't work as-is
        DoIt(param);

        manualResetEvent.Set();

        ... do more work ...
        ... call more functions ...
        }
    }
};
```

Any one have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this task in a thread-safe manner?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current design the simplest thing would be to pass in A to your object B, just like your doing with the manualresetevent:

```
B child = new B(this, manualResetEvent);
... etc...

Class B
{
private A parent;
private ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent;

public B(A p, ManualResetEvent mre)
{
    parent = p;
    manualResetEvent = mre;
    ... etc ...


private void Manage()
{
    ... do some work ...
    ... call some functions ...

    parent.DoIt(param);

    ... etc...
```

Of course you need to mark A.DoIt as public.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to only pass "this" and use parent.manualResetEvent instead?

Comment: Probably. But if you are concerned with good design then you should probably re-evaluate the entire thing, not just that one little thing.

Answer (score 0):

As with your previous question, you have to pass the instance of A you want to call the method on to B's constructor.

Comment: I always though that passing in THIS was horrible coding ... hopefully this is done byref and not byval because I could have 5-10 threads (instances of class B) going ... 

and this is considered thread safe? what if 2 children (class B) both call A.DoIt(...) at the same time?

Comment: Use a lock around code that can only be called 1-at-a-time. Without knowing what you're doing exactly in your work, it's hard to know why your code isn't thread-safe to begin with.

Comment: Can I lock a FUNCTION? Or do you mean lock(parent) itself when using DoIt?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with passing *this*.  If you are accessing any shared state (such as members of A), then you need to synchronize access to that.  BTW, it is bad to lock an entire object, you should be as granular as possible wrt locking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there must be some higher class that manipulates both classes A and B? Such as a GUI Form or the main thread?

You could have an event defined for Class B that triggers when work should be done. Have your form listen for the event, and when it comes in call the function in Class A.

It sounds as if your two classes are highly dependent on one another. If work in B depends on results in A, and vise-versa, you may want to reconsider how modular your classes actually are.

Comment: This is a service, there is a higher class (the service interface) but no GUI (no controls).